# End to end paypal payment in Flutter

Tags: flutter, paypal, payment

I am looking for a way to make in app payment using paypal so users can send money to each others (So, let's say a user A needs to buy something from user B)

While exploring packages on flutter pub.dev, I found that most of them facilitate payments to my account rather than enabling direct peer-to-peer transactions between users.

Please if there's anyone who have an idea about this and can help me out, will be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
I found a solution thanks to PrestonPHX comment

I am now trying to create flutter package to do this feature if any one needed this you can find it in my Github

Answer (score 1):

Using a [standard PayPal integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/), add an additional `payee` object [to the purchase_unit](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create!path=purchase_units/payee&t=request) of the v2/checkout/orders create API call.